# How to subtract second level columns in multiIndex level dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, multi-index

Here is the example data I am working with. What I am trying to accomplish is 1) subtract b column from column a and 2) create the C column in front of a and b columns. I would like to loop through and create the C column for x, y and z.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[100,200,400,500,111,222], [77,28,110,211,27,81], [11,22,33,11,22,33],[213,124,136,147,54,56]])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['x', 'y', 'z'], list('ab')])
print (df)
```

Below is what I am trying to get.

[image]

Comment: make disired output by text or image

Comment: I've attached the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) for select second levels with avoid remove first level with `drop_level=False`, then use `rename` for same MultiIndex, subtract and add to original with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), last use [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
dfa = df.xs('a', axis=1, level=1, drop_level=False).rename(columns={'a':'c'})
dfb = df.xs('b', axis=1, level=1, drop_level=False).rename(columns={'b':'c'})

df = pd.concat([df, dfa.sub(dfb)], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
     x              y              z          
     a    b    c    a    b    c    a    b    c
0  100  200 -100  400  500 -100  111  222 -111
1   77   28   49  110  211 -101   27   81  -54
2   11   22  -11   33   11   22   22   33  -11
3  213  124   89  136  147  -11   54   56   -2
```

With loop select columns by tuples, subtract `Series` and last use [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
for c in df.columns.levels[0]:
    df[(c, 'c')] = df[(c, 'a')].sub(df[(c, 'b')])

df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
     x              y              z          
     a    b    c    a    b    c    a    b    c
0  100  200 -100  400  500 -100  111  222 -111
1   77   28   49  110  211 -101   27   81  -54
2   11   22  -11   33   11   22   22   33  -11
3  213  124   89  136  147  -11   54   56   -2
```

Comment: Very nice, jezrael! Even providing two options. Thanks for providing the detailed explanation as well.

Comment: Just curious. Which option would be better? Is it the first option since no loop is involved?

Comment: @yeppi - It depends of data, I guess if many groups `len(df.columns.levels[0])` then first should be better, if few groups then second one.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = df.xs('a', level=1, axis=1)
b = df.xs('b', level=1, axis=1)
df1 = pd.concat([a.sub(b)], keys=['c'], axis=1).swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)
```

`df1`

```
    x       y       z
    c       c       c
0   -100    -100    -111
1   49      -101    -54
2   -11       22    -11
3   89       -11    -2
```

then at first concat df and df1 , next sort

```
pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

**other way**

use stack and unstack

```
df.stack(level=0).assign(c=lambda x: x['b'] - x['a']).stack().unstack([1, 2])
```

result:

```
    x           y           z
    a   b   c   a   b   c   a   b   c
0   100 200 100 400 500 100 111 222 111
1   77  28  -49 110 211 101 27  81  54
2   11  22  11  33  11  -22 22  33  11
3   213 124 -89 136 147 11  54  56  2
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Panda! It is super helpful. I am going to choose the other answer since he has gotten back a little quicker.

Comment: i don care you select what. don worry. i edited and append new answer. chk it for you!

Answer (score 0):

Dump down into numpy, build a new dataframe, and concatenate to the original dataframe:

```py
result = df.loc(axis=1)[:,'a'].to_numpy() - df.loc(axis=1)[:, 'b'].to_numpy()
header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['x','y','z'], ['c']])
result = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=header)
pd.concat([df, result], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)

     x              y              z
     a    b    c    a    b    c    a    b    c
0  100  200 -100  400  500 -100  111  222 -111
1   77   28   49  110  211 -101   27   81  -54
2   11   22  -11   33   11   22   22   33  -11
3  213  124   89  136  147  -11   54   56   -2
```

Another option, using `pipe`, without dumping into numpy:

```py
result = df.swaplevel(axis=1).pipe(lambda df: df['a'] - df['b'])
result.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([result.columns, ['c']])
pd.concat([df, result], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)

     x              y              z
     a    b    c    a    b    c    a    b    c
0  100  200 -100  400  500 -100  111  222 -111
1   77   28   49  110  211 -101   27   81  -54
2   11   22  -11   33   11   22   22   33  -11
3  213  124   89  136  147  -11   54   56   -2
```